# Accessing values in nested hash securly (without tripping over nil)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Given:

```
array = {first: {second: {one: 1, two: 2, three: 3 }}}
```

assuming anything can be `nil`, what would be the simplest/most concise way to access the nested values without tripping over nil? If any of the members doesn't exist, it should just return `nil`.

We came up with these:

Pure Ruby:

```
value = array.fetch(:first, {}).fetch(:second, {}).fetch(:four, nil)
value = begin array[:first][:second][:four]; rescue; end
```

Ruby on Rails:

```
value = array.try(:[], :first).try(:[], :second).try(:[], :four)
```

What can you come up with? Which method would you prefer, and why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is matter of coding style. With Ruby 2.0, you can also do this, which I may like better:

```
value = array[:first].to_h[:second].to_h[:four]
```

If you do not want to type `to_h` each time, you can define a method:

```
class Hash
  def safe_fetch k; self[k].to_h end
end
value = array.safe_fetch(:first).safe_fetch(:second)[:four]
```

Comment: Any idea how to define and use the `safe_fetch` method inside a Rails 5 application?

Answer (score -2):

I will prefer inline `rescue`, as it is more *Rubyistic*.

```
array = {first: {second: {one: 1, two: 2, three: 3 }}}
value = array[:first][:second][:four] rescue nil # => nil
value = array[:first][:second][:two] rescue nil # => 2
```

Comment: nice, didn't know that the rescue one could be shortened

Comment: A blind `rescue` is playing with fire and should be avoided whenever possible.